# Is Gmail Modifying Message Headers - SMTP

Tags: smtp, gmail

I sent a mail from my machine relayed through a <strike>public</strike> mail server to my gmail account using smtp on telnet.

now when i select show original on for that mail in my gmail account.

I see several headers just before the body of my mail.

```
X-TM-AS-Product-Ver:
X-TM-AS-Result:
X-imss-scan-details:
X-TM-AS-User-Approved-Sender:
X-TM-AS-User-Blocked-Sender:
```

Are these headers being added by gmail or my mail server. How do I find out.

Is this because of the process described in Section 3.8.1 of [this](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) rfc.

**Update:**
Can you give an example of the scenario given in this section of the rfc.
I am assuming that when my mail server sends a mail to a gmail account, the gmail server is a gateway as defined in the rfc as it is going into a different environment. Am i wrong?

Comment: Gmail servers are not the gateway (although I do not know how Google is handling this service, so this is pure speculation). If you send email to/from Gmail, then Gmail is the recipient/originating server. "Your" mail server is using a third party scanning/filtering service, that --among other things, I guess-- will add and/or rewrite the headers. That being said, I am really not getting what you are asking on your 'update.'

Comment: i want to see a practical example of mails passing through gateways. How do i do that?

Comment: gateways are explained here http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public mail server? What is that? Those headers come from Trend ScanMail. No relation to Gmail, or Google.

Comment: sorry for the wrong terminology.

Comment: Not a problem, I just wasn't too sure about what you mean.

Comment: see the update please